# Site with lightsail aws accessible at link ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/page

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a website that uses the AWS Lightsail server and in general everything works well.

But I see that the site can be accessed via the link "ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/page2", where the "XXX" is the IP address.

For users this is not a problem, but I have a serious problem with backlinks making the mentioned IP address point to my website's domain, as if it were spam.

How do I disable this?

As the site is made with Wordpress, I've already checked .htaccess and wp-config.php and everything seems to be ok. The website is only accessed without the "www", http redirects to https and if you enter the IP address, it automatically redirects to the domain.

Even so, none of this solves the problem with the "ec2.xxx.xxx" ip address

Comment: If the site is automatically redirecting from that domain to the real domain, then there should never be any backlinks to anything but the real domain. The website storing the backlinks should detect the redirect and store the final URL. Is there a specific website or service that is storing those bad URLs? And how are they even getting that URL?

Comment: I searched my site on Semrush, where it shows 48k backlinks, many of which are from my own site ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-compute1-amazonaws.com/anypage.

And I see that these links are really accessible.

Comment: When you say "from my own site ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-compute1-amazonaws.com/anypage", does that mean that your own website has links on it, that go to "ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-compute1-amazonaws.com" instead of to your domain name? If you view the HTML source of your website in a web browser, are the links to other pages on your website going to the correct domain or not?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it correctly...

In backlink audit tools, it shows that links like "ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-compute1-amazonaws.com/anypage" point to pages on my website like "sitedomain.com/anypage"-

Anyway, I believe that what I would need to do is disable access to the site via links like "ec2-xxx..."

Comment: I asked where those backlinks are coming from. You said you found them in a backlinks audit tool, but that tool should also be telling you where it *found* those links. You need to make sure those links aren't coming from your website. They probably are coming from your website, since it would be impossible for anyone else to guess that URL. You need to make sure you have `canonical` tags on your website that point to the correct domain instead of the "IP" domain. And you need to examine your website for any bad URLs and fix them.

Comment: I will check if there are links on the website that point to IP.

In any case, is it possible to disable access to the site via the "ec2-xxx..." link?

It should be accessible just to enter the domain in the browser.

Comment: You would probably need to do that in nginx, or apache, depending on which you are using. Or you could possibly do that at the CDN level, if you are using a CDN.

Comment: Ok...I don't know how to configure and prevent the site from being accessed by "ec2-xxx..amazon.com". I'll research and try to figure out what to do on the server.

Will all first-time users of the Lightsail service experience this issue? Because it seems that in the default configuration, this "ec2-xxx" link always exists.

Comment: That domain name to the server will always exist, it's the same with Lightsail and EC2. If you described exactly what software you are using (nginx or apache) an actual answer could be provided on here. My questions about where those links are coming from though, were because if you block that domain now, instead of setting up redirects, it could hurt your SEO (if that's something you care about).

Comment: Ok, I got it!

I'm using Apache on my AWS Lightsail instance.

The origin of these links are from the Google search console. There it shows that there are many "ec2-xxx" links pointing to correct links from the original blog...

I created rules in .htaccess to redirect any attempts to the original url, but it didn't work.

I believe that I don't have access via the "ec2-xxx..." link, but I'm kind of afraid these are "fake" backlinks, which could harm SEO authority (yes, maintaining good SEO is a concern).

I appreciate your comments!

Comment: @MarkB I managed to solve the problem.

I was trying to make redirects through the .htaccess file, but I only solved it when I made the redirection in the "wordpress-https-vhost.conf" file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.

I was trying to make redirects through the .htaccess file, but I only solved it when I made the redirection in the "wordpress-https-vhost.conf" file.

The code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(111.111.111.111|ec2-111-111-111-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Here, I entered the static IP of the site and the Amazon URL that was accessible.